# Can I delete private declarations from headers in possible SDK?

Tags: c++, dll, architecture, sdk

I am writing a little game engine and I need to give access to one class's methods for another class, and those methods mustn't be visible or accessible from client code. I think this is common problem.

We can use the "friend" keyword in C++ to solve this problem, but it is a bad solution, in addition, many other languages don't provide this keyword, like C#(but C# have another way for hiding methods from external code). 
We can use some patterns and relatively limit number of accesses.

But if I write library I can simple delete declarations of those methods from headers files. Those methods doesn't have to be exported from lib, they will be used only internally, in observer pattern, so it may unlikely crash engine at runtime.

Finally, **the question is,** is it good approach to prepare special versions of headers(with deleted private declarations) which will be packed in SDK, or the only approach in my case is the friend keyword usage?

P.S. If you have some info about how SDK should be, please leave a link.

Answer (score 1):

This is *much* worse than `friend`, use it or inheritance or better yet factor those methods out into a seperate compilation unit that your code only has access to.